# Noisy disparity map in stereovision pipeline

Tags: fpga, xilinx, stereo-3d

I'm trying to implement the Xilinx xfOpenCV stereovision pipeline explained [at the bottom page here](https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2019_1/sdaccel_doc/design-examples-using-libname-library-ats1510602888136.html) in Vivado HLS as standalone IP core (instead using accelerated flow). The stereo pipeline functions are based and very similar as the OpenCV ones.

So first I've collected a couple of images from an already calibrated stereo camera and I've simulated the xfOpenCV functions as standalone HW IP to make sure I've got the expected result, and after simulation the result is not perfect and it's got quite a lot of noise, for instance:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I went ahead and synthesize and implement the IP in the hardware (FPGA) to test it with a live stereo-camera stream. I've got the calibration parameters and are being used to correct the live stream frames before the 'stereo' function. (The calibration parameters also have been tested previously in simulation)

All works fine in terms of video flow, memory etc, but what I've got is a quite high level of noise (as expected from the simulation), this is a screen shot example of the camera live:

[image]

Any idea why this 'flickering' noise is generated? is it caused by the original images noise? what would it be the best approach or next steps to get rid of it (or smooth it)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can play with some of the parameters like CM_SIZE and WIN_ROWS. What is your current CM_SIZE ? If it is 3x3, try changing it to 7x7 or higher.

Comment: The CM_SIZE  I'm using is 9 (3x3) because is the camera matrix size and I can't change that. I tried different WIN_ROWS but it didn't make big difference...

Comment: My bad. I was talking about the window size of xf::StereoBM function. Try increasing the SAD_WINDOW_SIZE to 11 or 13.

Comment: Smaller SAD window means more details+more noise. Larger window means smoother, less details and fails near boundaries. I hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, I see, yes thanks for the suggestion, I've already tried to increase the SAD, did test different sizes (till 19) if it is much bigger than 11 (e.g 15) I get like a horizontal noisy lines in the image and if it is too small (around 7 or less) the noise is even higher, I'll try to change more combinations of the parameters and see if that improves it